# Literary and colloquial readings in English?

Tags: pronunciation

Some Chinese languages have the concept of [Literary and colloquial readings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literary_and_colloquial_reading), where the pronunciation of words, if you will, change between literary readings and vernacular readings.

Does English have this concept at all?!

(Perhaps something like want to vs. wanna?)

Comment: Many people change their accent and way of speaking depending on who their listener(s) are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't really exist in English, because even though there is colloquial speech, the *spelling actually changes*. For example, "want to" vs "wanna", or "is not" vs "ain't". 
However, in Chinese, the same character can itself be pronounced differently based on the setting.

The only comparable thing in English would be accents, but those depend on the origin of the speaker rather than the formality of the situation.

Comment: Well, there's certainly differences in pronunciation within dialects based on formality/register.  For instance, in informal speech, I'm much more likely to devoice vowels and create syllabic consonants.  Probably one of the most common pronunciation differences would be [iŋ] ~ [n̩] for ‹-ing› (SAE/AAVE), or [t] ~ [ʔ] for ‹-t-› (Cockney).